# Hide and show field after attribute change in Magento

Tags: magento, attributes, configurable-product

I'm building a Magento Store which sells doorhandles with different sizes. There are some standard sizes for which I made simple products, connected to a configurable product. Our client also wants to give customers the option to manually fill out a size. I made a simple product with the name 'custom doorhandle' and an attribute option in the attribute 'size' which says 'Other size'.

What I want is: when a customer selects the attribute option 'Other size' an extra field shows up where they can fill out the size of their needs. How can I do this? Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I actually found a solution myself: using the SCP (simple configurable product) Plugin, you can choose to display custom options withing a simple product. So I added the custom option as a textfield where customers can fill out 'other size' manually. If people select an existing size, the custom option field is not being displayed.